# Efficient way to filter against a list on the fly?

Tags: powershell, powercli

I'm trying to get a list of all VMs from vcenter, but exclude VM from the list, if its name contains one of the strings I have in another list.

```
$vm_list = Get-Datacenter | Get-VM 

$vm_list content:

vm1233
vm4566
vm7890
vm3330
vm9990
```

Now I want to exclude any VM that has one of the strings from the list in its name:

```
$exluded_vms = @('33', '66')
```

What's the best way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this:

```
[regex]$exluded_vms = '33|66'
 $vm_list = Get-Datacenter | Get-VM  | ? { $_.NAME -NOTMATCH $exluded_vms}
```

a more efficent way is using   `get-view`

```
   get-view -viewtype virtualmachine -filter @{'name'='^((?!33|66).)*$'}
```

last one give more information about VM, you can pipe the result to `| select name` to limit the ouptup